# How to find longest period with negative temperature

Tags: temperature, period

I have just 3 columns Station, Datee, Valuee(TEMPERATURE). 
50 years of daily temperature.
How to find longest period with negative temperature with MS SQL query?

Station Datee   Valuee

London  1/1/1961    2.4

London  1/2/1961    3.2

London  1/3/1961    9.8

London  1/4/1961    9.8

London  1/5/1961    5

London  1/6/1961    2.2

London  1/7/1961    1.1

London  1/8/1961    2.6

London  1/9/1961    2.4

London  1/10/1961   1.7

London  1/11/1961   0.3

London  1/12/1961   1.7

London  1/13/1961   -1.4

London  1/14/1961   -2.3

London  1/15/1961   -1.8

London  1/16/1961   -1.2

London  1/17/1961   -1.6

London  1/18/1961   -8.4

London  1/19/1961   -10.1

London  1/20/1961   -8.5

London  1/21/1961   -4.2

London  1/22/1961   -0.8

London  1/23/1961   4

London  1/24/1961   3

London  1/25/1961   0.8

London  1/26/1961   -3.4

Comment: What system are you using?  We cannot tell from your question.

Comment: Are you using Micrcsoft SQL?